# Can Envelope level Web hooks in Docusign leverage HMAC security?

Tags: docusignapi

Can we secure envelope level webhooks with HMAC security in Docusign? We are looking to switch to Envelope level from Account level as we don't need notifications to all documents in an account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely

You can find all the information on how to set it up in [this article](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/hmac/)

And how to validate it with code example on the [developer center](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/validate/).